# wpf mvvm - TextBox/TextBlock/CheckBox that is bound to IsSelected - I need to "grab" the input there to create a new object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

My textbox in xaml is this:

```
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="225" x:Name="cat" Margin="10"
                 Text="{Binding SelectedCategory.Category, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

And in my viewmodel I have the following:

```
        public string Category
    {
        get => _category;
        set
        {
            _category = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Category);
        }
    }
    private EventCategory _selectedCategory;
    public EventCategory SelectedCategory
    {
        get => _selectedCategory;
        set
        {
            _selectedCategory = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedCategory);
        }
    }
    public ICommand UpdateCommand { get { return new BaseCommand(ClickUpdate); } }
    private async void ClickUpdate()
    {
        ShowMessageBox("You clicked Update!");
        ButtonIsEnabled = false;
        Id = SelectedCategory.Id;
        Category = SelectedCategory.Category;
        IsActive = SelectedCategory.IsActive;
        var service = new DataService<EventCategory>(new TimeKeeprDbContextFactory());
        EventCategory eventCategory = await service.Get(Id);
        if (eventCategory == null)
        {
            ShowMessageBox("There is no such category. Please add a new one or chose another");
        }
        else
            eventCategory = await service.Update(Id, eventCategory);
    }
```

But of course, I'm getting an error on Category = SelectedCategory.Category;

What do I need to be able to do to "grab" the contents of the textbox (and the textblock and checkbox, of course) so that I can call my Update(Id) method?

I have it working in another class, but there my textbox was binding directly to the property:

```
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
             Text="{Binding Mode=Default, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource viewModel}, 
        Path=Password, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

I'm new to mvvm and data binding, so please be gentle :D

Comment: "I'm getting an error on Category = SelectedCategory.Category" - *what* error?

Comment: @ASh - System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

TimeKeepr.WPF.ViewModels.CategoriesViewModel.SelectedCategory.get returned null.

Comment: I think if you add that error to your question, it might be more clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in a section of my View that I didn't think was relevant - I had to change

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <me:CategoriesViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

to:

```
    <UserControl.DataContext>
    <me:CategoriesViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

That and a couple other small tweaks got the whole thing working.